# slick Database configuration/initialization not working using Database.forConfig(path)

Tags: scala, slick

I want to use pooled database connections, by using HikaryCP. So I got in my dependencies:

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % Version.slick
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % Version.slick
```

Then in my scala code, I use:

```
  /** Does not work, see Exception below */
  def createPooledDatabase(): Database = {
    Database.forConfig("myConfig.jdbc")
  }

  /** Works fine, but does not use connection pooling. */
  def createDatabase(): Database = {
    val config: Config = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("myConfig.jdbc")
    val driver = config.getString("driver")
    val url = config.getString("url")
    val user = config.getString("user")
    val password = config.getString("password")
    Database.forURL(url, user = user, password = password, driver = driver)
  }
```

Using the createPooledDatabase() for initialization I get on execution of first SQL-Statement:

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: rental-connect.jdbc - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:676)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:190)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:155)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100)
        at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:14)
        at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.<init>(JdbcBackend.scala:494)
        at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:46)
        at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:37)
        at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(BasicBackend.scala:250)
        at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession$(BasicBackend.scala:249)
        at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(JdbcBackend.scala:37)
        at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.run(BasicBackend.scala:275)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Most likely I am doing something wrong, can somebody explain?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, the configuration structure seems to have to be slightly different of what you have:

```scala
mydb = {
  dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
  properties = {
    databaseName = "mydb"
    user = "myuser"
    password = "secret"
  }
  numThreads = 10
}
```

See https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.0/database.html and the scaladoc https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.0/api/index.html#slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef@forConfig(String,Config,Driver,ClassLoader):Database

Comment: Well, the documentation allows a lot of different ways to configure a Database, you posted one way to use a DataSource. I do not want this, instead I want to use the variant where I specifiy url, driver, user and password.
According to the [documentation](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.0/api/index.html#slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef@forConfig(String,Config,Driver,ClassLoader):Database) that should work.